# How can I parse command line arguments that themselves contain switches using boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I'm writing a program in C++ that is a wrapper for some benchmarks that contains some setup code at the beginning and analisys code in the end.

I want to run up to two benchmarks in parallel.  The original commandlines for these are:

```
/path0/benchmark0 -switch0 -switch1 -switch2
/path1/benchmark1 -arg0 -arg1 -arg2 -arg4
```

And I want to put these on my wrapper's commandline:

```
wrapper -setup_arg0 -setup_arg1 -analysis_arg0 --command0 /path0/benchmark0 -switch0 -switch1 -switch2 --command1 /path1/benchmark1 -arg0 -arg1 -arg2 -arg4
```

Where I want to get two `std::vector<std::string>`s, one for each of `command0` and `command1`, containing the original commandlines.  This is how I'm doing it (using `boost::program_options`):

```
("command0", po::value<std::vector< std::string> >(&command0)->multitoken(), "command line for thread 0")
("command1", po::value<std::vector< std::string> >(&command1)->multitoken(), "command line for thread 1")
```

and this basically works.  However, if the benchmark's arguments begin with `-` (as most switches on most programs I've seen do), the `program_options` tries to parse them as part of the wrapper's switches, because it doesn't know that they should be grouped together under `command0` or `command1`.

Does `program_options` support that?  If so, how?

---

**Example:**

Where I work there is a convention for doing this by "terminating" the multitoken like this:

```
wrapper <snip> --command0 /path0/benchmark0 -switch0 -switch1 -switch2 -command0-
```

(in this example I terminated `--command0` with `-command0-`.)

How can I make `program_options` handle it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best if you take `command0` and `command1`'s values as a single string. e.g.,

```
wrapper --command0 "/path0/benchmark0 ..." --command1 "/path1/benchmark1 ..."
```

Yes, there's more work for you in that you have to `wordexp` your respective command strings (unless you're already just passing those strings straight to the shell ;-)), but it more cleanly separates out what's for the wrapper and what's for the invoked commands.

Comment: I need to pass the commands into `exec`.  Is there a good way to pass a string like this into `exec`, or would I need to break that up into an array of strings?  Is that what `wordexp` does?

Comment: If your command string is trusted (i.e., you don't have to worry about attackers, etc.), just use `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, static_cast<char*>(0))`. If it's not trusted, then yes, use `wordexp` to expand.